# Stop threads from interleaving output

Tags: multithreading, haskell, io, stm, io-monad

The following program creates two threads running concurrently, that each sleep for a random amount of time, before printing a line of text to stdout.

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad
import System.Random

randomDelay t = randomRIO (0, t) >>= threadDelay

printer str = forkIO . forever $ do
  randomDelay 1000000 -- μs
  putStrLn str

main = do
  printer "Hello"
  printer "World"
  return ()
```

The output generally looks something like

```
>> main
Hello
World
World
Hello
WoHrelld
o
World
Hello
*Interrupted
>>
```

How do you ensure that only one thread can write to stdout at a time? This seems like the kind of thing that STM should be good at, but all STM transactions must have the type `STM a` for some `a`, and an action that prints to the screen has type `IO a`, and there doesn't seem to be a way to embed `IO` into `STM`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The way to handle output with STM is to have an output queue that is shared between all threads and which is processed by a single thread.

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.STM
import Control.Monad
import System.Random

randomDelay t = randomRIO (0, t) >>= threadDelay

printer queue str = forkIO . forever $ do
  randomDelay 1000000 -- μs
  atomically $ writeTChan queue str

prepareOutputQueue = do
    queue <- newTChanIO
    forkIO . forever $ atomically (readTChan queue) >>= putStrLn
    return queue

main = do
  queue <- prepareOutputQueue
  printer queue "Hello"
  printer queue "World"
  return ()
```

Answer (score 6):

Locking in the way you're describing isn't possible using`STM`. This is because `STM` is based on optimistic locking and so every transaction must be restartable at any point. If you embedded an `IO` operation into `STM`, it could be executed multiple times.

Probably the easiest solution for this problem is to use a `MVar` as a lock:

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.MVar
import Control.Monad
import System.Random

randomDelay t = randomRIO (0, t) >>= threadDelay

printer lock str = forkIO . forever $ do
  randomDelay 1000000
  withMVar lock (\_ -> putStrLn str)

main = do
  lock <- newMVar ()
  printer lock "Hello"
  printer lock "World"
  return ()
```

In this solution the lock is passed as an argument to `printer`.

Some people prefer to declare the lock as a [top-level global variable](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Top_level_mutable_state), but currently this requires `unsafePerformIO` and relies on properties of GHC that AFAIK aren't part of the Haskell Language Report (in particular, it relies on the fact that a global variable with non-polymorphic type is evaluated at most once during the execution of a program).

Answer (score 4):

A bit of research, based on [Petr Pudlák's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20854864/546084) shows that there is a module [Control.Concurrent.Lock](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/concurrent-extra-0.7.0.4/docs/src/Control-Concurrent-Lock.html) in the [concurrent-extra](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/concurrent-extra-0.7.0.4) package that provides an abstraction around `MVar ()`-based locks.

The solution using that library is

```
import           Control.Concurrent
import qualified Control.Concurrent.Lock as Lock
import           Control.Monad
import           System.Random

randomDelay t = randomRIO (0, t) >>= threadDelay

printer lock str = forkIO . forever $ do
  randomDelay 1000
  Lock.with lock (putStrLn str)

main = do
  lock <- Lock.new
  printer lock "Hello"
  printer lock "World"
  return ()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the example using global lock as mentioned by Petr.

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad
import System.Random
import Control.Concurrent.MVar  (newMVar, takeMVar, putMVar, MVar)
import System.IO.Unsafe (unsafePerformIO)


{-# NOINLINE lock #-}
lock :: MVar ()
lock = unsafePerformIO $ newMVar ()



printer x = forkIO . forever $ do
   randomDelay 100000
   () <- takeMVar lock
   let atomicPutStrLn str =  putStrLn str >> putMVar lock ()
   atomicPutStrLn x

randomDelay t = randomRIO (0, t) >>= threadDelay



main = do
  printer "Hello"
  printer "World"
  return ()
```

Comment: What advantage does this have over Petr's solution?

Comment: In case you don't want to pass around the lock as a function argument. Suppose this printer function is called frequently through out code base, 1 less argument make it feel more like the native print function.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually implement a lock using STM if you want, though an `MVar` will almost certainly perform better.

```
newtype Lock = Lock (TVar Status)
data Status = Locked | Unlocked

newLocked :: IO Lock
newLocked = Lock <$> newTVarIO Locked

newUnlocked :: IO Lock
newUnlocked = Lock <$> newTVarIO Unlocked

-- | Acquire a lock.
acquire :: Lock -> IO ()
acquire (Lock tv) = atomically $
  readTVar tv >>= \case
    Locked -> retry
    Unlocked -> writeTVar tv Locked

-- | Try to acquire a lock. If the operation succeeds,
-- return `True`.
tryAcquire :: Lock -> IO Bool
tryAcquire (Lock tv) = atomically $
  readTVar tv >>= \case
    Locked -> pure False
    Unlocked -> True <$ writeTVar tv Locked

-- | Release a lock. This version throws an exception
-- if the lock is unlocked.
release :: Lock -> IO ()
release (Lock tv) = atomically $
  readTVar tv >>= \case
    Unlocked -> throwSTM DoubleRelease
    Locked -> writeTVar tv Unlocked

data DoubleRelease = DoubleRelease deriving Show
instance Exception DoubleRelease where
  displayException ~DoubleRelease = "Attempted to release an unlocked lock."

-- | Release a lock. This version does nothing if
-- the lock is unlocked.
releaseIdempotent :: Lock -> IO ()
releaseIdempotent (Lock tv) = atomically $ writeTVar tv Unlocked

-- | Get the status of a lock.
isLocked :: Lock -> IO Status
isLocked (Lock tv) = readTVarIO tv
```

`acquire`/`release` pairs need careful masking and exception handling, much like primitive `MVar` operations. The documentation suggests, but does not actually state, that STM operations are interruptible when they `retry`; assuming this is true, the same approach used for `withMVar` will work here. Note: I've opened a [GHC ticket](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/19028) to document `retry` interruptibility.